# Why don't my list items that I made with module css appear side by side?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

My react.js codes are here:

```
>     
>     function Navbar() {
>       return (
>         <header className={styles.navbar}>
>             <img src={Logo} />
>             <nav>
>                 <ul>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href='/'>Learn More</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href='/'>Log In</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href='/'>Sign Up</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <AiOutlineSearch />
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <AiOutlineUser />
>                 </li>
>                 </ul>
>             </nav>
>             <div className={styles.mobile_btn}>
>                 <AiOutlineMenu size={25} />
>             </div>
>         </header>
>       )
>     }
>     
>     export default Navbar

In my css codes are here:

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
  }

.menu {
    display: inline-block;
}


  .mobile_btn {
    display: none;
  }
```

I used google to find where the error was coming from but no matter what I did it didn't work. Can someone who knows the CSS module help? I'm afraid of going crazy if I try a little harder.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.  Are you getting an error message or it doesn't look right on the page?  If the latter, a screenshot would help as we can't see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
```